# Get string representation of created element

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering how to get a string representation of an element created using jQuery

Something like this:

`var myFrame = $("iframe",{src:"http://google.com" scrolling:"no"});`

Resulting in: `<iframe src="http://google.com" scrolling="no"></iframe>`

instead of: `[object Object]`

I realize that I can create the string from the start, but for readability and the sake of being difficult, I'd like to know how to do it.

Comment: You probably wanted `var myFrame = $("<iframe>",{src:"http://google.com", scrolling:"no"});` (note the < and > and the comma)

Comment: Yeah - I missed the < and > in this case but I did actually have the comma in my actual code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the `outerHTML` of the DOM element :

```
var html = myFrame[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: Thanks! Combined with the missing < and >, that did the trick. Now to wait for the stupid 10 minute wait so that I can accept your answer.